# Give key for each dictionary key value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am running this code to combine three lists into a dictionary with the first list being the key.

```
list_dict = {x: (y, z) for x, y, z in zip_longest(order_instance, final_mem, final_disk)}
pprint(list_dict)
```

which returns this...

```
{'instanceIndex:0': ('212590592', '192389120'),
 'instanceIndex:1': ('5971968', '13963264'),
 'instanceIndex:2': ('93331456', '216592384')}
```

I would like to be able to format this dictionary to show keys for the y and z value, making it easier to input into a SQL db. Something like this.

```
{'instanceIndex:0': ((Memory: '212590592'),
                      (Disk: '192389120')),
 'instanceIndex:1': ((Memory: '5971968'),
                      (Disk: '13963264')),
 'instanceIndex:2': ((Memory: '93331456'),
                      (Disk: '216592384'))}
```

Comment: Minor: `('Memory': '212590592')` instead of `(Memory: '212590592')`?

Comment: That whole last part has some invalid syntax. Do you want nested dictionaries or tuples? Also, could you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly modify your dict-comprehension to match whatever format you choose to store your values. In your case, your key-value format resembles a `dict`ionary -- so use that.

```
list_dict = {x: {'Memory':y, 'Disk':z} for x, y, z in zip_longest(order_instance, final_mem, final_disk)}
#               ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^ ^
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax

Comment: @MadPhysicist Forgive me. I haven't Pythoned for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to store your data as *named tuple*:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from collections import namedtuple
from pprint import pprint

inst = ["i1","i2","i3"]
memo = ["1","2","3"]
disk = ["d1","d2","d3"] 

Data = namedtuple("Data", ["Memory","Disk"])

k = {x: Data(m,d) for x, m, d in zip_longest(inst,memo,disk)}

pprint(k)
```

Output:

```
{'i1': Data(Memory='1', Disk='d1'),
 'i2': Data(Memory='2', Disk='d2'),
 'i3': Data(Memory='3', Disk='d3')}
```

You can access named tuples either by index or by name:

```
print( k["i1"].Memory)   # 1 
print( k["i1"][1])       # d1
```